# I am trying to setup vue-styleguidist on a vue 2 project but styleguide fails because webpack does not match API schema

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, vuepress, vue-styleguidist

Setup vuepress for my vue project no problem and wanted to you vue-styleguidist to auto document everything. Installed it and its dependencies within /docs/ with vuepress but I don't understand the webpack validation error below.

command

```
npm run styleguide
```

results in the below error and I can't seem to figure it out.

```
 ERROR  ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.node should be one of these:
   false | object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
   -> Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff.
   Details:
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'setImmediate'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'process'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'dgram'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'fs'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'net'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'tls'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'child_process'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.node should be one of these:
   false | object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
   -> Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff.
   Details:
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'setImmediate'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'process'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'dgram'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'fs'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'net'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'tls'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    * configuration.node has an unknown property 'child_process'. These properties are valid:
      object { __dirname?, __filename?, global? }
      -> Options object for node compatibility features.
    at validate (..\docs\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:105:11)
    at validateSchema (..\docs\node_modules\webpack\lib\validateSchema.js:78:2)
    at create (..\docs\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:109:24)       
    at webpack (..\docs\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:151:32)      
    at f (..\docs\node_modules\webpack\lib\index.js:55:16)
    at createServer (..\docs\node_modules\vue-styleguidist\lib\scripts\create-server.js:45:42)
    at server (C..\docs\node_modules\vue-styleguidist\lib\scripts\server.js:14:49)
    at Object.commandServer (..\docs\node_modules\vue-styleguidist\lib\scripts\binutils.js:130:41)
    at Object.server (..\docs\node_modules\vue-styleguidist\lib\scripts\index.js:88:25)
    at ..\docs\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-styleguidist\index.js:49:64   
    at Service.run (..\docs\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:230:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (..\docs\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js:36:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
```